# How to properly `Iscatter` list or numpy array from Python to C++ with mpi4py?

Tags: python, c++, openmpi, mpi4py

I have `worker` code written in C++ and `manager` code in Python.

I call the workers from the manager with `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn()` and I would like to scatter some data to the workers. Something like this:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import os

cpp_mpi_info = MPI.Info.create()
cpp_mpi_info.Set("path", os.getcwd())
inter_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Spawn("./worker", maxprocs=4, info=cpp_mpi_info)
send_buf = [5, 6, 7, 8]
request = inter_comm.Iscatter(send_buf, None, MPI.ROOT)
request.Wait()
```

The worker code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Comm inter_comm;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&inter_comm);
    int send_buf;
    int recv_buf;
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Iscatter(&send_buf, 1, MPI_INT, &recv_buf, 1, MPI_INT, 0, inter_comm, &request);
    MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The `MPI_Wait()` is necessary, because `MPI_Iscatter()` is non-blocking. But this `MPI_Wait()` throws a `MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated` error.

So I assume it has something to do with the data preparation on the manager side.

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth I may have found a solution.

The `inter_comm.Iscatter()` function needs a buffer for sending. However it is not explicitly explained how to create such a buffer. It was hidden in one of the examples in the [PDF User Manual](https://mpi4py.github.io/mpi4py.pdf) unter section 3.3 Collective communication.

There, they use a Numpy array as send buffer, which is created like this:

```py
send_buf = np.array([5,6,7,8], dtype="i")
```

You can create an empty recive buffer like this:

```py
recv_buf = np.empty(4, dtype="i")
```

It is basically the same like creating every Numpy array, but the `dtype` is very importand. It is not possible to use either one of the Numpy data types (like `np.int32`, `np.float64`, `np.complex128`, etc.) or a Python data type (like `int`, `float`, `str`, etc.). You expicitly have to use the data types represented as string (`"i"`, `"u"`, `"f"`, `"c"`, and so forth). This is because this are the [Array Interface](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface) data types. I assume this is necessary to make sure a certain memory layout is used so MPI C++ at the reciving end can understand the data.

Comment: MPI does not provide type information in the messages. It is your responsibility to ensure that the MPI datatype you specify in MPI calls (e.g., `MPI_INT`) corresponds to the actual type of the data in the message and that it is the same (or at least congruent) on both ends of the communication. `mpi4py` hides that complexity from you by automatically supplying the correct MPI datatype, but you need to match it with whatever the C++ end is expecting.